# Gradient on the hyperbolic plane

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

Consider the hyperbolic plane
\begin{align}
\mathbb{H}^2=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}_+\times \mathbb{R}\}
\end{align}
with some metric $g$.
Is there something like the Voss-Weyl formula for the gradient? I want to use this formula to compute $b\cdot \nabla$ for some vector field $b$ on $\mathbb{H}^2$ in terms of the gradient $\nabla_g$with respect to the given metric $g$. So I'm not looking for $\nabla X$ but only the "gradient vector" representation. I would be grateful for any hints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key point is that your metric $g$ sets up a non-degenerate pairing between the two vector fields. This can be used to define a gradient in the following way: The gradient $\nabla_g u$ of a smooth function $u: \mathbb{H}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is defined as the unique vector field satisfying
$$
\langle \nabla_g u, V \rangle_g=du(V)
$$
for all vector fields $V \in \mathfrak{X}(\mathbb{H^2})$ and $du$ is the differential; a $1$-form in this case. However, if we examine this in coordinates, this means that
$$
\nabla_g u^T G V=\nabla u^T V
$$
where $G >0$ is a symmetrix, $2 \times 2$ positive definite matrix representing the metric tensor and $du(V)=\nabla u^T V$. Note we did another remarkable thing here: We identified the differential with a vector. In the euclidean case, this is pretty much clear and well-known.

Since this identity has to hold for any $V \in \mathfrak{X}(\mathbb{H}^2)$, the problem boilds down to a matrix-vector equation. Next, we can take the transpose and just invert $G$ to arrive at the formula
$$
\nabla_g u=G^{-1}\nabla u
$$
You now have a matrix-vector type formula for $\nabla_g u$. You can choose any type of metric you like, i.e.
$$
G=\frac{1}{y^2}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
and try this formula out.

Comment: thanks for your answer! You said for a smooth function but if I want to apply this theory on PDE's I wouldn't in general talk about smooth functions but rather integrable functions. Do you know if this is transferable to the case of some Sobolev function?

Comment: Yes, the formula holds also in the Sobolev case, but of course only in some almost everywhere or distributional sense. You can check that as follows: It holds on smooth functions and by approximation, also on Sobolev functions. Note that many authors defined Sobolev spaces on Riemannian manifolds (such as this) as the completion of the space of compactly smooth functions w.r.t. to the Sobolev norm, so approximation is a freebie.